# Need to get the credits remaining for each user of their recent purchase only for the users who purchased credits <= 100

Tags: mysql, sql

Only if the used_at and expired_at is `null` the credit is counted as remaining credit

user table:

| id | email |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row |
| 2 | row |

user_credit table:

| id(pk) | user_id(fk) | purchase_date | no.of.credits purchased |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-07-21 | 150 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-06-03 | 5 |

user_credit_history table:

| credit_id(fk) | used_at | expired_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-06-03 | null |
| 1 | null | null |
| 2 | 2022-07-02 | null |

The query I use is:

```
select u.id, u.email, u.name, uc.id as credit_id, uc.added_at as purchase_date, uc.credits_added, count(uch.credit_id) as credits_remaining 
from user u 
left join user_credit uc on uc.user_id = u.id 
left join user_credit_history uch on uch.credit_id = uc. 
where uc.type='CREDIT' 
    and uc.credits_added >= 100 
    and (uch.used_at is null and uch.expired_at is null) 
group by uch.credit_id 
order by uc.added_at desc;
```

But this query is giving me all the purchase details of each user but I only need latest one.

Comment: you forgot to put the query you tried and the expected results

Answer (score 0):

instead of joining the table "user_credit_history" you can use a subselect to get the 1 row you want per user by using order by in your subselect for the field "used_at".

Answer (score 0):

```
1. you can use :-

SELECT 
    u.id,
    u.email,
    u.name,
    uc.id AS credit_id,
    uc.added_at AS purchase_date,
    uc.credits_added,
    COUNT(uch.credit_id) AS credits_remaining
FROM
    user u
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        user_id, id, added_at, credits_added
    FROM
        user_credit
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING MAX(purchase_date)) AS uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
        LEFT JOIN
    user_credit_history uch ON uch.credit_id = uc.id
WHERE
    uc.type = 'CREDIT'
        AND uc.credits_added >= 100
        AND (uch.used_at IS NULL
        AND uch.expired_at IS NULL)
GROUP BY uch.credit_id
ORDER BY uc.added_at DESC;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand because there is no expected results...
This query calculated for each user its latest purchase and fetches it and calculates the remaining credits for the credit_id of the latest purchase of the user and I've added the 100 filter:

```
select u.id, u.email, u.name, uc.id as credit_id, uc.added_at as purchase_date, uc.credits_added, count(credit_id) as credits_remaining
from
   (
      select user_id, max(added_at) as latest_purchase
      from user_credit
      group by user_id
   ) up
   inner join user_credit uc on uc.user_id=up.user_id and uc.added_at=up.latest_purchase
   inner join users u on u.id=uc.user_id
   inner join user_credit_history uch on uch.credit_id=uc.id
where uc.type='CREDIT' and 
      uc.credits_added >= 100 and 
      used_at is null and expired_at is null
group by uch.credit_id, u.id, u.email, u.name, uc.id as credit_id, uc.added_at as purchase_date, uc.credits_added
```